# How to allow multiple syntax options in MATLAB function calls

Tags: matlab, syntax

I am writing a set of customized plot functions in MATLAB, whose aim is to ensure a more consistent look of our company charts and to be fast.

In these customized functions, I would like to reproduce MATLAB's variability in allowing multiple syntax options for function calls, similar to the syntax options available for MATLAB's `plot` function.

So, say my function is `plotFun.m`, then the following function calls should all work:

```
plotFun(y)
plotFun(x,y)
plotFun(ax,_)
plotFun(_,Name,Value)
```

I am familiar with `inputParser` and several other techniques to parse name-value pairs passed as `varargin`, yet I cannot figure out how to parse the first arguments, that is `ax`, `x` and `y`...

I have scanned the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) and found several contributions for parsing name-value pairs (somehow overlapping with the `inputParser` functionality), but none of them seems to do the trick in this case.

EDIT:

In reply to thewaywewalk 's comment, here are some more details regarding what the syntax options should do.
Suppose `plotFun` does something similar as the `line` function (but with other defaults and a different set of allowed options).

`y` should be validated to be a numerical vector 
`x` (if present) should be validated to be a numerical or datetime vector

`plotFun(x,y)` 
If `x` is of class datetime, `x = datenum(x)`, then 
call `line(x,y, 'Parent',gca)`

`plotFun(y)` 
should set `x = 1:numel(y)`, then call `line(x,y, 'Parent',gca)` as above

`plotFun(ax,_)` 
should do the same as above, but call `line(x,y, 'Parent',ax)` instead of `gca`

`plotFun(_,Name,Value)` 
should parse and validate the name-value pairs and pass them to the call of `line`. I solved this task with the help of `inputParser`.

EDIT 2

In the world of my dreams, hitting `Ctrl + F1` for `plotFun` would show the function hints, that is, a list of allowed syntax options (like the one I typed in the code block above), as opposed to showing a more cryptic `plotFun(varargin)`...

Comment: What you want is possible, but you should give us some more code to play with. For example post some simplified code for the four variations you want to achieve (as single functions) and we can help to combine them.

Comment: What about conditions for the type of input? E.g. `if ischar(input1) ...`

Comment: Maybe get some inspiration by typing `edit plot` into Matlab

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just go input by input and check cases? For instance, check if the first argument is a handle to an axes, otherwise use `ax=gca`. Next check whether the next 2 arguments are valid as `y` or `x,y`, etc. When all your explicit syntax is done, you can wrap up the param-value pairs with `inputParser`.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I have added some examples in the post above.

Comment: @Wauzl: plot is a built-in function, so editing does not reveal that much...

Comment: @Andreas Deak: I was originally thinking about a similar approach, but thought it to be a bit too clumsy, I was hoping for something more elegant... But maybe this is the way to go.

Comment: Just noticed that a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732064/implementing-multiple-syntaxes-for-a-matlab-plot-function?rq=1) has been asked before, but left without a satisfactory answer... So, it's still hot :-)